# How to export trained model from local version of H2O to import into a remote instance of H2O?

Tags: h2o

I want to install H2O alongside an existing web application.  I want the web app to call the H2O REST API to make predictions.  This would all be installed on a customer's data centre.  I would not have access to this remote instance of H2O at all.

Is there a way to export a model trained in an instance of H2O on my PC in a way that it can be imported into the customer's instance of H2O?

Answer (score 1):

Shoulda RTFM!

```
GET /99/Models.bin/<model-id>
POST /99/Models.bin
```

More details in the H2O REST API:

http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-simons/4/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html#route-%2F99%2FModels.bin%2F(%3F%3Cmodelid%3E.*)